# converting XML to CSV where different tags in XML and their respective sub tags become line items of the CSV

Tags: xpath, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am trying to get the attribute tags within accessory tag to be line items of a CSV file

I have tried to iterate using map function but im just getting one  value at a time.**What i want is there are two Accesory Type tag in this XML i want their respective attribute tags to become each line item in the CSV**

```
 <Accessory Type="Panel">
    <PartNumber>9021447</PartNumber>
    <Attribute Name="DescCode">Operating Panel, White/PI White, Low E SmartSun Tempered Glass</Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Mark_ID">41424</Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Order_Quantity">1</Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="QUOTE_QUANTITY">1</Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Quote_Quantity_Extended">1</Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="MarkName">0001</Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="US_ENERGY_STAR_CLIMATE_ZONE">Northern</Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="SubUnitID">1</Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="AW_Control_2">47AoYY</Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="ReferenceID">3</Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="OrderPONum"/>
    </Accessory>
    <Accessory Type="Screen">
    <PartNumber>2505930</PartNumber>
    <Attribute Name="Total_Pre_Price_in_USD">208.70</Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Total_Price_in_USD">208.700</Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="QUOTE_QUANTITY">1</Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Quote_Quantity_Extended">1</Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="DescCode">Insect Screen, Gliding, White</Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Mark_ID">41424</Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Order_Quantity">1</Attribute>
    </Accessory>
```

I have tried to make the attributes under accessory tag to become line items.

Expected output:
9021447|Operating Panel, White/PI White, Low E SmartSun Tempered Glass|41424 
//and in the next line
25005930|208.70|1 //and so on

This is the code that i have tried
    %dw 2.0
    output application/json
    ---
    payload.m2oFile.m2oOrder.Unit.*Accessory map (value, index) -> { 
        (index) : value.*Attribute filter($.@Name == "MarkID"),
        (index) : value.*Attribute filter($.@Name == "PRODTYPE"),
        (index) : value.*Attribute filter($.@Name == "UNIT_CODE")
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this approach..

```
 %dw 2.0 
 output application/csv header=false
 --- 

 (payload.a.*Accessory map {
      PN: $.PartNumber,
      ($.*Attribute map  {
        (($$) : $)  if (isEmpty($) == false)
 })
 }
 )
```

Should give you the output as follows:

[image]

PS: i had to add "a" as the root to the xml as otherwise the xml would not be well formed..